# Is there a method literal?

Tags: go

Is it possible to define a method literal? Something like the code below but working.

```
type Fn struct{
    sw Dialer
}
var x fn
fn := func (x Fn) Reboot() error {  }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/A3YVCQbVFZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use a "function value", so that it can be assigned later on. A common one in network related packages is for a struct to have a `Dial func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)` field that can be replaced with a custom dialer (e.g. [http.Transport](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport))

```
type Fn struct {
    Reboot func() error
}

func main() {
    f := Fn{}
    f.Reboot = func() error {
        return nil
    }
    f.Reboot()
}
```

Comment: Well handled--wish the q were clearer so more people could benefit but we can't do much about that.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm using it ... a custom dialer.